# Assigning to a shared_ptr, is there a way to do it?

Tags: c++

is there a way of first initialize shared_ptr with nullptr and after some time assing a pointer to a class to it?

```
//pseudo code
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr(nullptr);  
//and later
ptr->assign(new MyClass);
```

Comment: Check this out: http://codepad.org/1N84El9d

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for `ptr.reset( new MyClass )`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [shared_ptr::reset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset):

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr;

ptr.reset(new MyClass);
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not as efficient as calling reset, but this should also work. Create an inline temp instance of shared_ptr and assign it.

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr;

ptr = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass);
```